# How to list countries of customers in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have several users and these users have several customers. Every customer has a country attribute. I want to listing customer's country in my project. I tried it with a for loop but when several customers have same countries it is listed same countries several times. I want to listed all countries just one time. How can I do that?

Here are my codes

**views.py**

```
def country_customer_list(request):
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(company=userP[0].company.comp_name)


    context = {
        'customer_list': customer_list,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'country_customer_list.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ..
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**country_customer_list.html**

```
                                <table id="multi-filter-select" class="display table table-striped table-hover grid_" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Country</th>
                                            <th>Operations</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    {% for customer in customer_list %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{customer.country}}</td>

                                            <td>
                                                ...
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your field country which is a `CharField` should actually be a `ForeignKey` to a table `Country`. This way your model design would actually be better. (Plus it would prevent issues like someone enters `Abc` and someone else `abc` (note the capitalization) causing it to be considered two different countries). With your current models you would have to make distinct queries (Also above stated issues like capitalization / typos etc. would need to be considered) etc.

Comment: In views.py, this `userP[0]` should throw an error, because `get` only returns one Model instance, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want a list of all distinct values in the `country` field, you could use `distinct()`:

```
countries = Customer.objects.values_list('country', flat=True).distinct()
```

the `values_list(flat=True)` converts the result into a flat list of only that one value the query is intersted in.